# How to run all of my php if function

Tags: php, mysql

Why my all if function not run. Only first one run and other not. If I submit  my form with the value `A1, A2, A3` it not save all the value at a time but it save the first one. If I submit it individually then works fine.

**HTML FORM**

```
   <form  method="post" action="booking.php" class="form-horizontal ticket-form pull-right" role="form">

                             <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="ticket_no" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Your Seat: </label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-8">
                                  <?php 
                                    $bus_name = $_GET['bus_name'];
                                    $date = $_GET['date'];
                                    $time = $_GET['time'];

                                  ?>
                                      <input class="form-control selected-ticket" id="ticket_no" name="ticket_no" value=""type="text" readonly="readonly" >
                                      <input class="form-control" id="ticket_id" name="ticket_id" value="<?php echo $ticket_id ;?>" type="hidden" >
                                      <input class="form-control" id="user_id" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" type="hidden" >
                                      <input class="form-control" id="bus" name="bus_name" value="<?php echo $bus;?>" type="hidden" >
                                      <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" type="hidden" >
                                      <input class="form-control" id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo $time;?>" type="hidden" >

                                  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group seats-container">
<input name="A1" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="seatvalue" value="A1">
<input name="A2" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="seatvalue" value="A2">
<input name="A3" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="seatvalue" value="A3">
                                </div>
                                <!--Your input field willbe visible here-->
                            </div>


                            <p>Seat No: <span class="ticket-count" id="ticket-count" > </span></p>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="discount" class="col-lg-4 control-label view-discount">Discount: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="discountdis" placeholder="Click on Discount" disabled>
                                    <input class="form-control discount hide" id="discount" name="discount" type="text" onkeyup="CalcDiscount();" autocomplete="off" max="4">
                                </div>
                                <label for="total-price" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Total Price: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <input class="form-control total-price" id="total-price" name="totalprice" type="text" readonly="readonly">
                                </div>
                                <label for="customername" class="col-lg-4 control-label"> Customer Name: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="customername" name="customername" type="text" >
                                </div>
                                <label for="customermobile" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Customer Mobile </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="customermobile" name="customermobile" type="text" >
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <button type="reset" id="clearbutton" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ">Clear</button><button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Continue</button>

                         </form>
```

**php code**

```
 $sql_1 = "SELECT ticket_id FROM ticket_details WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";
    $res_1 = mysql_query($sql_1);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_1);
    $get_id=$row['ticket_id'];
    $ticket_status = '1';

 if(isset($_POST['A1'])){

    $seat_no = $_POST['A1'];

        if (!$get_id==$ticket_id){
            $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."')";
            $res_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);
                if(!$res_2) return 1;
            return 99;
            }
        if ($get_id==$ticket_id){
    $sql_3 = "UPDATE ticket_details SET ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";        
            $res_3 = mysql_query($sql_3);
                if(!$res_3) return 1;
            return 99;
        }
}
if(isset($_POST['A2'])) {
    $seat_no = $_POST['A2'];

        if (!$get_id==$ticket_id){
            $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."')";
            $res_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);
                if(!$res_2) return 1;
            return 99;
            }
        if ($get_id==$ticket_id){
          $sql_3 = "UPDATE ticket_details SET ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";      
            $res_3 = mysql_query($sql_3);
                if(!$res_3) return 1;
            return 99;
        }
}
if(isset($_POST['A3'])){
    $seat_no = $_POST['A3'];

        if (!$get_id==$ticket_id){
            $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO ticket_details (ticket_id,".$seat_no.") VALUES('".$ticket_id."','".$ticket_status."')";
            $res_2 = mysql_query($sql_2);
                if(!$res_2) return 1;
            return 99;
            }
        if ($get_id==$ticket_id){

            $sql_3 = "UPDATE ticket_details SET ".$seat_no." = '".$ticket_status."' WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'";        
            $res_3 = mysql_query($sql_3);
                if(!$res_3) return 1;
            return 99;
        }
}
```

Comment: You have return statements inside ifs

Comment: i have added my html form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that all possible branches within `if(isset($_POST['A1'])){` end with a `return`. That means that execution can never reach `if(isset($_POST['A2'])) {`.

Comment: So should  I remove this and check the full with a `echo` message ?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I have total 41 input field like A1,A2,A3......... depend on user input. each field make 3 database query and its a long process that's why I try to set `if(isset($_POST' so it will not query all the statement and loading time will decrease